# how separate Entity Reference in view?

Tags: views, entities

I have two content type, content type A and content type B , I used Entity Reference field in content type B to reference content type A.

I created view with field Entity Reference ,In Entity Reference there are more field included how can i separate this all field in view ?

Answer (score 1):

Add a "Relationship" to your view:

[image]

And then select "Entity Reference" in the "Filters" select list. You can choose whether is a content entity that is referenced, or referencing.